# Join on three tables with same columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

```
[users]
id BIGINT,
name VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
role ENUM('admin', 'executive', 'pos')
...

[transactions]
id BIGINT
fname VARCHAR(255),
lname VARCHAR(255),
mobile CHAR(10),
email VARCHAR(255),
amount FLOAT(7, 2),
verified_by BIGINT NOT NULL        # Refers to user.id
...

[refunds]
id BIGINT
transaction_id BIGINT,
amount FLOAT(7,2)
initiated_by BIGINT NOT NULL,      # Refers to user.id
processed_by BIGINT NULL           # Refers to user.id
...
```

I want to join the refunds table such that it shows the transaction information as well as the users.name for both refunds.initiated_by and refunds.processed_by. Since a refund is initiated by a user with role pos and later processed by another user with role executive. I don't want to split the users table into users, executives and pos as except for role, all other fields will be same for all three.

Currently I can get the transaction information as well as the name of the user who initiated the refund.

```
SELECT refunds.id, fname, lname, mobile, transactions.email,
       transactions.amount AS transaction_amount, refunds.amount AS refund_amount,
       users.name AS initiated_by, refunds.processed_by
FROM refunds 
JOIN transactions
    ON refunds.transaction_id=transactions.id 
JOIN users
    ON users.id=refunds.initiated_by;
```

This gives me everything except the name of the user that processed the refund. How do I get that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do a second join to the `users` table to bring in the name of the user that processed the refund:

```
SELECT r.id,
       t.fname,
       t.lname,
       t.mobile,
       t.email,
       t.amount AS transaction_amount,
       r.amount AS refund_amount,
       u1.name AS initiated_by,
       u2.name AS processed_by,
       r.processed_by
FROM refunds r
INNER JOIN transactions t
    ON r.transaction_id = t.id 
INNER JOIN users u1
    ON u1.id = r.initiated_by
INNER JOIN users u2
    ON u2.id = r.processed_by
```